# Hibernate Criteria like on numeric field

Tags: java, hibernate

face error while adding LIKE on criteria for numeric field

**Code:**

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.like("id", value, MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
```

**Output on Console:**

```
Hibernate: select this_.id as id0_0_, this_.firstName as firstName0_0_ from Employee this_ where this_.id like ?
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
```

**Note:**
already tried `sqlRestrictions`, here i used id field but in my scenario user select search field, so its hard to get SQL field for user selected field. used annotation based hibernate()see below function.

```
public static Criteria addSearch(Criteria criteria, String field, String value){
      criteria.add(Restrictions.like(field, value, MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
      return criteria;
}
```

**Complete Stacktrace:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.LongTypeDescriptor.unwrap(LongTypeDescriptor.java:36)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BigIntTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(BigIntTypeDescriptor.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:283)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.bindPositionalParameters(Loader.java:1873)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.bindParameterValues(Loader.java:1844)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1716)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:801)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2533)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1716)
    at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:347)
    at exec.Main.main(Main.java:68)
```

Comment: right, i already mentioned in question that field is choosen by user and search value is also given by user via HTTP so i dont know what is a data type of input.

Comment: @Chaitanya : added function in question, i used every time this function to change criteria runtime.

Comment: where is your answer ?.

Comment: I removed my answer as it doesn't help your scenario, I suggest you to update your question to add more details with small example because it is difficult to assume for others what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

From the exception log, it looks like it's the casting issue. Have you tried `String valueStr = String.valueOf(value);`(assume the variable value is long type)?

And for `LIKE` operation, you will want to add the '%' sign to the string, `"%".concat(valueStr).concat("%")`,

Answer (score 0):

```
Restriction.like() is causing casting problem. You can use criteria to build a sqlRestriction for the same


        criteria.add(Restrictions
                .sqlRestriction("{alias}.id LIKE ('%value%')"));
```

This works for me